# Match three game

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a project and I need to make a Match-Three game and I need to check with jQuery if 3 or more candies are next to each other but can't figure it out.

There's one column of 7 and this is the code to fill it with random images:

```js
$(".element").attr('src', function() {
  var candy = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1);
  return "image/" + candy + ".png";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-1">
  <img src="" class="element">
  <img src="" class="element">
  <img src="" class="element">
  <img src="" class="element">
  <img src="" class="element">
  <img src="" class="element">
  <img src="" class="element">
</div>
```

As you can see, I have 4 different candies. The thing that I need is for the program to check if 3 or more candies are aligned and remove them.

Any help or tip would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a try, have a look

```js
function draw(){
$(".element").each(function(){
 var candy = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1);
  var src=  "image/" + candy + ".png";
$(this).attr('src',src);
$(this).attr('candy',candy);
});
}
function validate(){

 var v= -1;
 var counter = [];
 $(".element").each(function(){
   var candy = $(this).attr("candy");
      if (counter.length<=3){
   if (v == candy)
    {
       counter.push(this);         
    }else {
    if (counter.length<=3){
       v = candy;
      counter =[];
      counter.push(this)
      }
   }
  }
 
 });
 
 
 console.clear();
console.log(counter.length + " elements next to eachother") 
if (counter.length>2)
    console.log(counter) // here you could remove then or whatever
    else console.log("fail, there is less then three element next to eachother, try agen")
draw()
}

draw()
```

```html
<script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-1">
  <img src="" class="element">
  <img src="" class="element">
  <img src="" class="element">
  <img src="" class="element">
  <img src="" class="element">
  <img src="" class="element">
  <img src="" class="element">
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="validate()" value="validate" />
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks!!!

Now I'm trying to figure out how to delete the candies

Comment: toeasy `counter.forEach((x=> x.remove()));` will remove the candies